# Solrj index string containing html in java

Tags: java, html, solr, solrj

I know how to index a html page I downloaded using:

```
ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

    up.addFile(new File(fileName), solrId);
    up.setParam("literal.id", solrId);
    up.setAction(ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
    getServer().request(up);
```

If I have the html page in a string `String mystring` how can I index it without having to save it to a file and read it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `addFile` method, use `addContentStream` with a `ContentStreamBase.StringStream`. This will make the CeontentStreamUpdateRequest pull its data from a `String` instead of a file.

Related documentation:

- [ContentStreamBase.StringStream](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/util/ContentStreamBase.StringStream.html)
- [ContentStreamUpdateRequest.addContentStream](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/ContentStreamUpdateRequest.html#addContentStream(org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStream))